# How do I draw a circle in JS using SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg

If you look at http://map-icons.com/ and the js included with the file contains these variable declarations:

```
// Define Marker Shapes
var MAP_PIN = 'M0-48c-9.8 0-17.7 7.8-17.7 17.4 0 15.5 17.7 30.6 17.7 30.6s17.7-15.4 17.7-30.6c0-9.6-7.9-17.4-17.7-17.4z';
var SQUARE_PIN = 'M22-48h-44v43h16l6 5 6-5h16z';
var SHIELD = 'M18.8-31.8c.3-3.4 1.3-6.6 3.2-9.5l-7-6.7c-2.2 1.8-4.8 2.8-7.6 3-2.6.2-5.1-.2-7.5-1.4-2.4 1.1-4.9 1.6-7.5 1.4-2.7-.2-5.1-1.1-7.3-2.7l-7.1 6.7c1.7 2.9 2.7 6 2.9 9.2.1 1.5-.3 3.5-1.3 6.1-.5 1.5-.9 2.7-1.2 3.8-.2 1-.4 1.9-.5 2.5 0 2.8.8 5.3 2.5 7.5 1.3 1.6 3.5 3.4 6.5 5.4 3.3 1.6 5.8 2.6 7.6 3.1.5.2 1 .4 1.5.7l1.5.6c1.2.7 2 1.4 2.4 2.1.5-.8 1.3-1.5 2.4-2.1.7-.3 1.3-.5 1.9-.8.5-.2.9-.4 1.1-.5.4-.1.9-.3 1.5-.6.6-.2 1.3-.5 2.2-.8 1.7-.6 3-1.1 3.8-1.6 2.9-2 5.1-3.8 6.4-5.3 1.7-2.2 2.6-4.8 2.5-7.6-.1-1.3-.7-3.3-1.7-6.1-.9-2.8-1.3-4.9-1.2-6.4z';
var ROUTE = 'M24-28.3c-.2-13.3-7.9-18.5-8.3-18.7l-1.2-.8-1.2.8c-2 1.4-4.1 2-6.1 2-3.4 0-5.8-1.9-5.9-1.9l-1.3-1.1-1.3 1.1c-.1.1-2.5 1.9-5.9 1.9-2.1 0-4.1-.7-6.1-2l-1.2-.8-1.2.8c-.8.6-8 5.9-8.2 18.7-.2 1.1 2.9 22.2 23.9 28.3 22.9-6.7 24.1-26.9 24-28.3z';
var SQUARE = 'M-24-48h48v48h-48z';
var SQUARE_ROUNDED = 'M24-8c0 4.4-3.6 8-8 8h-32c-4.4 0-8-3.6-8-8v-32c0-4.4 3.6-8 8-8h32c4.4 0 8 3.6 8 8v32z';
```

Now, all I want, is to add another one, a circle.

Can anyone please point me in the direction of a resource or tool with which I can achieve this?  Does anyone know what those little bits even mean?

Comment: the title should probably be: how do I draw an SVG circle using js :-)

Comment: but it looks like you don't need js, just some basic svg knowledge. So go on, read up :-)

Comment: Do you have any idea where?  I have no idea where to start.  I get results like: `<svg height="10000" width="10000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
         <circle id="cir1" cx="300" cy="300" r="40" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="" fill="none"/>
</svg>`

Comment: See this [converter](http://complexdan.com/svg-circleellipse-to-path-converter/)